# Can I replace code in main() into a constructor of a global object?

Tags: c++, global-variables, program-entry-point

**Assuming** that `init` is the last global object being initialized before `main()` (and we don't need any command line argument), can I do something like:

```
struct int_main {
  int_main ()
  {
    //... start code execution
  }
}init;

int main ()
{
}
```

Asking the question in this way, because I am interested in knowing if `main()` assures anything other than:

1. argc, argv from command line
2. All global objects are initialized
   before it

Comment: Not all globals are initialized before main.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>You would have a hard time catching any exception from the `int_main` constructor.</del>

Also you would have a hard time returning a process exit code with complete unwinding of the stack.

That's mainly what `main` provides in C++: a place to catch exceptions, and a means to return normally (not just `exit`) with a specified process exit code.

Cheers &  hth.,

Comment: What is the problem with exceptions ?

Comment: `main()` can't catch exceptions thrown by statics constructed before it's entered, so I can't see the benefit of `main()` there...?  Excellent point re process exit codes and stack unwinding... +1.

Comment: Just an FYI re `exit()`, 3.6.1-4: "If exit is called to end a program during the destruction of an object with static storage duration, the program has undefined behavior." - so can't call it from `~int_main()`.

Comment: I think I may have written something stupid about exceptions here. This was just a few seconds before I crashed (sleep). Possibly futile to ask but, could anyone enlighten me about what I was thinking of?

Answer (score 5):

You do not have a guarantee that *all* global objects are constructed before your object, so you may not use any of them. That includes vital parts of iostreams.

I normally use the pattern that `main()` just constructs the application object and invokes a method on it to perform the actual work.

Answer (score 0):

In theory this is possible, but you're not assured of the initialization order of global objects, so you are not going to have an assurance of which object will be initialized last, and therefore you're going to have a problem with running a "main" inside a global object that may not have the proper state of the program setup before its constructor is called.  Furthermore, you're not going to be capable of suspending the execution of your "main" object's constructor to wait for the proper starting state to exist if such a scenario occurs.

Additionally, since the OS's runtime will be calling your actual `main()` function in order to actually "run" your program regardless of the presence of a "main" global object or not, you're going to need to return a value from 'main()` in order for the OS runtime to determine the exit status of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Within C\C++ you can declare the entry point of your application via the visual studio IDE. It's the convention that the entry point into you're code will be either be Main or in the case of a win32 exe WinMain.

As to answer your question, the CRT will iniailize all global variables in the order of

C Primitive Types
C Struct Types and or C++ Class types
Call the class constructors
Call the Entry point into your application, this will be done from CRTStartup (correct me if i'm wrong)